# Bash script to iterate contents of directory moving only the files not currently open by other process

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have people uploading files to a directory on my Ubuntu Server.

I need to move those files to the final location (another directory) only when I know these files are fully uploaded.

Here's my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/uploaded_by_users

for filename in *; do

        lsof $filename

        if [ -z $? ]; then
          # file has been closed, move it           
        else
          echo "*** File is open. Skipping..."
        fi

done

cd -
```

However it's not working as it says some files are open when that's not true. I supposed $? would have 0 if the file was closed and 1 if it wasn't but I think that's wrong.

I'm not linux expert so I'm looking to know how to implement this simple script that will run on a cron job every 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

`[ -z $? ]` checks if `$?` is of zero length or not.  Since `$?` will never be a null string, your check will always fail and result in `else` part being executed. 
You need to test for numeric zero, as below:

```
lsof "$filename" >/dev/null; lsof_status=$?
if [ "$lsof_status" -eq 0 ]; then
  # file is open, skipping
else
  # move it
fi
```

Or more simply (as Benjamin pointed out):

```
if lsof "$filename" >/dev/null; then
  # file is open, skip
else
  # move it
fi
```

Using negation, we can shorten the if statement (as dimo414 pointed out):

```
if ! lsof "$filename" >/dev/null; then
  # move it
fi
```

You can shorten it even further, using `&&`:

```
for filename in *; do
  lsof "$filename" >/dev/null && continue  # skip if the file is open
  # move the file
done
```

Comment: Or directly `if lsof "$filename"; then`?

Comment: Negating the conditional, as `if ! lsof "$filename"; then` allows you to get rid of the "skip" block too, and just put the move logic directly in the if block.

Comment: Thanks guys. Do I have to run my .sh script as root? Otherwise it seems not to work.

Comment: Who is the owner of `/var/uploaded_by_users`?  Run as that user.

Comment: Ok, it works, BUT, I see a strange behaviour. I run it and it prints "File XXX can be moved" I run it again and it says it's open. Why? I'm considering using somethng like seconds elapsed since last modification to a file to consider it closed. May this be possible? lsof doesn't seem to be consistent

Comment: This is not working. I'm using lsof on a file which I'm copying (1gb) and lsof returns 1

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to worry about when the write is complete, if you are moving the file to a different location in the same file system. As long as the client is using the same file descriptor to write to the file, you can simply create a new hard link for the upload file, then remove the original link. The client's file descriptor won't be affected by one of the links being removed.

```
cd /var/uploaded_by_users
for f in *; do
    ln "$f" /somewhere/else/"$f"
    rm "$f"
done
```

Comment: Neat idea.  I think the OP wants the `/somewhere/else` to have only those files that have been completed the transfer.

Comment: I'm moving only after the upload is complete because there are some other cron jobs that run on the final directory and those scripts assume files are closed and completed (files are images)

Comment: Good points. What is actually receiving the file, i.e., what process is writing the file into `/var/uploaded_by_users`? `rsync`, for example, can be configured to write incoming data to a temporary directory until all the data is received, at which point it links the file atomically into the "real" destination. The end result is that `/var/uploaded_by_users/foo.txt` wouldn't actually appear in the file system until it was completed, with the incoming data actually being written to something like `/var/uploaded_by_users/tmp/foo.txt-in-progress` until the upload is complete.

Comment: @chepner how do you do that? Thanks